# Change button position on bootstrap gallery full screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize the bootstrap gallery full screen starting from this tutorial [bootstrap gallery full screen](http://bootply.com/59900)

the code:

```
<div class="container fill">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item">    
  <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://www.mysite/images/category/image.jpg');background-position: center;">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>TITLE</h1>
          <p class="lead">Description</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="categories.php?id=17">View Gallery</a>
  </div>
   </div>
     </div>
<div class="pull-center">
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

as you can see, the class that contains the button "View Gallery"
is positioned within the classes "item" and "fill"

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="categories.php?id=17">View Gallery</a>
```

For graphic reasons, I have to place the button in the fixed position at the bottom right of the screen, but **must remain** within the original classes.
I have tried in various ways, but I can not get it on the visualization for mobile devices.
for example, I'm trying to optimize viewing on iphone5 (640 x 1136) **@media (max-width: 768px)** using this class applied to the button:

```
.gallery-button {  
  text-align:right;
  background-color: transparent; 
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px; 
  top: 350px; left:150px;
}
```

In portrait mode would be fine, but in lanscape the button disappears.
ok, how can I solve the problem for all types of display?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix for all scenarios, you should specify the position from bottom and right if you want it in the bottom right.

```
.gallery-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

That should fix your problem for all screen sizes.